# How to return Dialog.Delegate directive to Alexa Skill model?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I want to create a simple multi-turn dialog with the Alexa Skill model. My intent consists of 3 slots, each of which are required to fulfill the intent. I prompt every slot and defined all of the needed utterances.

Now I want to handle the request with a Lambda function. This is my function for this specific Intent:

```
function getData(intentRequest, session, callback) {
    if (intentRequest.dialogState != "COMPLETED"){
        // return a Dialog.Delegate directive with no updatedIntent property.
    } else {
        // do my thing
    }
}
```

So how would I go on to build my response with the `Dialog.Delegate` directive, as mentioned in the Alexa documentation?

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/dialog-interface-reference.html#scenario-delegate

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With `Dialog.Delegate` directive you cannot send `outputSpeech` or `reprompt` from your code. Instead those defined in interaction model will be used.

> Do not include outputSpeech or reprompt with the Dialog.Directive.
>   Alexa uses the prompts defined in the dialog model to ask the user for
>   the slot values and confirmations.

What this means is that you cannot `delegate` and provide your own response, but instead you can use any other `Dialog` directive to provide your `outputSpeech` and `reprompt`.

Ex: `Dialog.ElicitSlot`, `Dialog.ConfirmSlot` and `Dialog.ConfirmIntent`.

At any point, you can take over the dialog rather than continuing to delegate to Alexa.

```
...
    const updatedIntent = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent;
    if (intentRequest.dialogState != "COMPLETED"){
       return handlerInput.responseBuilder
              .addDelegateDirective(updatedIntent)
              .getResponse();
    } else {
        // Once dialoState is completed, do your thing.
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
              .speak(speechOutput)
              .reprompt(reprompt)
              .getResponse();
    }
...
```

The `updatedIntent` parameter in `addDelegateDirective()` is optional.
It is an intent object representing the intent sent to your skill. You can use this property set or change slot values and confirmation status if necessary.

More on Dialog directives [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/dialog-interface-reference.html#directives)

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I struggled with the alexa documentation, this was very helpful.

Comment: @Cicil I would recommend you add how to get the currentIntent for reference

Comment: const currentIntent = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent

Answer (score 5):

In nodejs you can use

```
if (this.event.request.dialogState != 'COMPLETED'){
    //your logic
    this.emit(':delegate');
} else {
     this.response.speak(message);
     this.emit(':responseReady');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped to get a grip of the mechanics at work.

Comment: this is v1 code. the answer from Cicil uses v2 so it's preferable

Answer (score 4):

In nodeJS we can check the dialogState and act accordingly.

```
if (this.event.request.dialogState === 'STARTED') {
      let updatedIntent = this.event.request.intent;
      this.emit(':delegate', updatedIntent);
} else if (this.event.request.dialogState != 'COMPLETED'){
     if(//logic to elicit slot if any){
          this.emit(':elicitSlot', slotToElicit, speechOutput, repromptSpeech);
     } else {
          this.emit(':delegate');
     }
} else {
     if(this.event.request.intent.confirmationStatus == 'CONFIRMED'){
           //logic for message
           this.response.speak(message);
           this.emit(':responseReady');
     }else{
           this.response.speak("Sure, I will not create any new service request");
           this.emit(':responseReady');
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the code snippet. I went with another solution but it helped a lot to understand this elicitSlot functionality.